# height auto but with a maximum depending on parent and brothers height

Tags: html, css

I have three divs inside a 300*300px parent div. I want the first two divs with height auto, but the third must have a maximum and an overflow-y scroll bar, so we keep this three divs inside their parent div.

[image]

As you can see,I need to keep the green div inside the red div wathever the brothers height. Any idea on how to do this with CSS or even JS?

The snippet:

```css
.container{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .row{
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
        .row1{
            background-color: rgb(200,130,0);
            height: auto;
        }
        .row2{
            background-color: rgb(200,230,0);
            height: auto;
        }
        .row3{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            background-color: rgb(0,200,130);
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        <div class="row row2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit impedit, at natus voluptate amet harum accusantium obcaecati magnam pariatur, iusto consequuntur a, illo quo laboriosam esse temporibus cupiditate explicabo laudantium.</div>
        <div class="row row3">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis cumque at vitae nulla, eligendi ea provident natus tempora illum. Maiores, culpa nisi at dolore veniam alias quam. Odit, fugit voluptatum. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, distinctio. Fuga ullam eius, sapiente ab officia voluptatum magni quam, iure illum, voluptate unde dignissimos. Iusto modi quis fugit nemo beatae!</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using flexbox in CSS. To keep the bottom row inside the parent container add-

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

It will pull all the content from row 3 into the parent.

I created an example based on your question in CodePen https://codepen.io/ryanindustries8/pen/zYOpNex?editors=1100

I also added box-sizing: border-box to pull in the 8px padding to keep all the content within the height and width set by the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something which can resize itself if you change the parent div height you can try this js code

```
    var row3 = document.querySelector('.row3')
    var row1 = document.querySelector('.row1')
    var row2 = document.querySelector('.row2')
    var container = document.querySelector('.container')

    var row1Height =parseInt(getComputedStyle(row1).height.replace('px','')) //37.33px
    var row2Height =parseInt(getComputedStyle(row2).height.replace('px','')) //112px
    var containerHeight =parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).height.replace('px','')) //300px

    var row3Height =containerHeight -row2Height - row1Height //132px
    row3.style.height=row3Height.toString()+'px'
```

Comment: cool solution but in the real project I have lots of this divs so I've created a loop for each .container and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: auto;` on the green div, and `box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the red (parent) div. Do NOT use javascript.

Comment: I need to keep that 300px in the red div.

Comment: You can :) just add these properties as well.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it solves your question. Thank you!